# Get the output of minerd.exe synchronous

Tags: c#

Basically Im trying to start a process and get the output. The program is minerd.exe (bitcoin cpu miner) https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer for reference
I tried something like this :

```
private  void StartMining()
        {

            Process p = new Process();
            StreamWriter sw;
            StreamReader sr;
            StreamReader err;
            ProcessStartInfo psI = new ProcessStartInfo(@"miners\minerd.exe");
            psI.Arguments = "-o " + miner.PoolIp + ":" + miner.PoolServerPort + " -O " + miner.PoolUsername + ":" + miner.PoolPassword;
            psI.UseShellExecute = false;
            psI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psI.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psI.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo = psI;
            p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);

            p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_ErrorDataReceived);
            p.Start();


            p.BeginOutputReadLine();

        }

        private void proc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteLogWindow(e.Data, Color.Green);
        }

        private void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteLogWindow(e.Data, Color.Red);
        }
 private delegate void DelegateInsertNewLineToLogRichTextBox(string text, Color color);
        void WriteLogWindow(string text, Color color)
        {
            if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                DelegateInsertNewLineToLogRichTextBox method = new DelegateInsertNewLineToLogRichTextBox(InvokedInsertNewLineToLgoRichTextBox);
                Invoke(method, new object[2] { text, color });

            }
            else
            {
                InvokedInsertNewLineToLgoRichTextBox(text, color);

            }
        }
        private void InvokedInsertNewLineToLgoRichTextBox(string message, Color color)
        {
            richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Arial", 8F, FontStyle.Bold);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color;
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = Environment.NewLine + message + "\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss d/M/yyyy");
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
```

The miner seems to be working but i get no output.

Thanks in advance for any advices

Comment: It seems that the output it's actually in Error stream even if even if the program worked correctly so now i get the output from error stream . This is a little weird. But Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get the output of a program you need to do

```
p.WaitForExit();
int retVal = p.ExitCode;
```

note that `WaitForExit` will halt your thread so you shouldn't to it on the UI thread

note also that the `ExitCode` will return the what "minerd" return in it's `main` function, not the actual output (`WriteLine`) of "minerd"

Comment: I need the output asynchronous

Comment: This is asynchronous @adisba . you might meant you want it synchronous?

Comment: if you'll use the code that i gave you in the UI thread then it's gonna be synchronous @adisba . however, it is going to make the program look STUCK, so if minerd takes time i'd suggest you make it asynchronous and show the user a progress bar or something of sort

Comment: actually minerd is running long periods so i'l get the output after a very long time

Comment: then create a new thread to run it and wait for it to end. when it end use invoke to interfere with the UI thread and reenable everything

Comment: No actually you were right but it seems that the output it's actually in Error stream even if even if the program worked correctly .

Comment: @adisba: So you should call `BeginErrorReadLine` as per my answer - then you can get the error data as it's written, rather than waiting for the process to exit.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling [`BeginErrorReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginerrorreadline.aspx), so you won't be getting any error results - perhaps all the output is reported via the error stream?

Comment: @LovesTha: Right, which explains everything - basically calling `BeginErrorReadLine` as well as `BeginOutputReadLine` should make it work.